# Scrapy shell XPATH not working

Tags: scrapy

I tried the following XPATH in XPATHHelper in Chrome and XPather in Firefox and it always displays all the snippets(ie the description of the search results) in google search result page, but it does not work in the Scrapy shell:

```
//span[@class='st']
```

In case it matters, I invoke scrapy shell like this:

```
scrapy  shell "http://www.google.com/search?q=myQuery"
```

and I say `hxs.select("//span[@class='st']")`. This always returns an empty list.
Any clues as to why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy is not able to "parse" sites that need Javascript execution. What different developer consoles show you is the already interpreted and executed site with all Javascripts applied.

Since Google displays its resulst with the help of Javascript, the Scrapy on its own can't handle this.

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved. I try with javascript disabled and then Scrapy crawls those XPATHs now.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes sites will not work with Javascript Disabled (Applebees.com for example) so you have to use an actual browser like Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox url bar type :
    about:config
find the line javascript.enable and change its value to false

Install FireFinder extension
Open Firebug (F12)

and then enjoy scraping google like xpath expression :

```
//*[@id="search"]//li[@class="g"]/div[@class="s"]//cite
```